# Al recorrer un array de objetos, quiero ejecutar una función de cada objeto pero no lo realiza

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

Sigo practicando ejercicios, tengo el siguiente problema:
Al final de mi código quiero mediante un ciclo for ejecutar la función estadoAlumnos sin importar la cantidad de objetos que tenga mi colección de Arrays, realice primero un console.log(alumnos[i]) y todo bien, recorre los elementos del array y me los regresa ya con las calificaciones actualizadas por el prompt. El problema es cuando quiero que ejecute la función estadoAlumnos en cada uno de los objetos, solamente realiza el de el elemento con indice 0.

```
var jorge = {
name: "Jorge",
lastName: "Martínez",
age: 25,
hobbie: "futbol",
cursando: true,
saludar: saludar,
estatus: estatus,
materias: {
    español: 0,
    ingles: 0,
    matematicas: 0,
    quimica: 0,
    fisica: 0,
    literatura: 0
},
promediando: promediando,
promedio: 0
}

var jose = {
name: "Jose Luis",
lastName: "Lopez",
age: 25,
hobbie: "futbol",
cursando: true,
saludar: saludar,
estatus: estatus,
materias: {
    español: 0,
    ingles: 0,
    matematicas: 0,
    quimica: 0,
    fisica: 0,
    literatura: 0,
},
promediando: promediando,
promedio: 0
}

var alumnos = [jose, jorge];

function calificando(alumno) {
alumno.materias.español = parseInt(prompt("Ingresa la calificación final de Español del alumno " + alumno.name + " " + alumno.lastName + ": "), 10)
alumno.materias.ingles = parseInt(prompt("Ingresa la calificación final de Ingles del alumno " + alumno.name + " " + alumno.lastName + ": "), 10)
alumno.materias.matematicas = parseInt(prompt("Ingresa la calificación final de Matemáticas del alumno " + alumno.name + " " + alumno.lastName + ": "), 10)
alumno.materias.quimica = parseInt(prompt("Ingresa la calificación final de Química del alumno " + alumno.name + " " + alumno.lastName + ": "), 10)
alumno.materias.fisica = parseInt(prompt("Ingresa la calificación final de Fisica del alumno " + alumno.name + " " + alumno.lastName + ": "), 10)
alumno.materias.literatura = parseInt(prompt("Ingresa la calificación final de Literatura del alumno " + alumno.name + " " + alumno.lastName + ": "), 10)
} 


function califi() {
for(i = 0; i < alumnos.length; i++){
    calificando(alumnos[i])
}
}
califi()



function estatus() {
if(this.cursando === true){
    console.log("El alumno " + this.name + " " + this.lastName + " tiene estatus activo en este momento")
} else {
    console.log("El alumno " + this.name + " " + this.lastName + " tiene estatus inactivo en este momento")
}
}

function saludar() {
console.log("Hola mi nombre es " + this.name + " " + this.lastName)
}

function promediando() {
    let calificaciones = Object.values(this.materias)
    let suma = 0;
    let noAcreditadas = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < calificaciones.length; i++) {
        suma = suma + calificaciones[i];
        if(calificaciones[i] < 6) {
            noAcreditadas++
        }
    }
    let prom = suma / calificaciones.length;
    this.promedio = prom.toFixed(2);
    if(noAcreditadas > 2 || this.promedio < 7) {
        this.cursando = false;
}
}



function estadoAlumnos() {
for(i = 0; i < alumnos.length; i++) {
    alumnos[i].promediando();            
}
}


estadoAlumnos();
```

Answer (score 2):

### Actualización de la respuesta

El problema es el ámbito (scope) de la variable `i` en estas lineas:

```
for(i = 0; j < alumnos.length; i++) {
...
for(i = 0; i < calificaciones.length; i++) {
```

Tal como indica @StialManstike en los comentarios de esta respuesta:

> cuando declara el for sin hacer var i lo que hace es declarar
> implicitamente i como global, por eso el valor se mantiene despues del
> ciclo for porque queda como window.i en el dom
>
> asi que la solucion tambien podria ser usar var para declarar la
> variable en cada ciclo for.

Así pues, la solución correcta seria aplicar el `var` en dichos bucles:

```
for(var i = 0; j < alumnos.length; i++) {
...
for(var i = 0; i < calificaciones.length; i++) {
```

Investigando esta nueva respuesta, he visto que con `let` también hubiera funcionado:

```
for(let i = 0; j < alumnos.length; i++) {
...
for(let i = 0; i < calificaciones.length; i++) {
```

Lo cual me ha llevado a investigar las diferencias entre `var` y `let`, pues desconocia que afectaba a los `for` de este modo, y finalmente leyendo [este enlace](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-var-let-and-const-keywords-in-javascript/?ref=rp) (en inglés) he podido entenderlo y practicarlo bien (me hubiera gustado reproducir su tabla final aquí, pero dudo que les hubiera gustado).

En esta [documentación sobre var](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) dicen lo siguiente:

> Descripción
>
> Las  declaraciones de variables, donde sea que ocurran, son procesadas
> antes de que cualquier otro código sea ejecutado. El ámbito de una
> variable declarada con la palabra reservada var es su contexto de
> ejecución en curso, que puede ser la función que la contiene o, para
> las variables declaradas afuera de cualquier función, un ámbito
> global. Si re-declaras una variable Javascript, esta no perderá su
> valor.
>
> Asignar un valor a una variable no declarada implica crearla como
> variable global (se convierte en una propiedad del objeto global)
> cuando la asignación es ejecutada.

En esta otra [documentación sobre let](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) encontramos su definición formal:

> let
>
> La instrucción let declara una variable de alcance local con ámbito de
> bloque(block scope), la cual, opcionalmente, puede ser inicializada
> con algún valor.

La otra forma de declarar una variable, en javascript, es con `const`, donde de nuevo, en su documentación, encontramos su ámbito también:

> Las variables constantes presentan un ámbito de bloque (block scope)
> tal y como lo hacen las variables definidas usando la instrucción let,
> con la particularidad de que el valor de una constante no puede
> cambiarse a través de la reasignación. Las constantes no se pueden
> redeclarar.

Gracias de nuevo a @StialManstike por su comentario. Me ha hecho investigar sobre el tema más profundamente, pues sin haberme documentado antes, creía que entendia bien el funcionamiento de las variables en javascript, pero estaba totalmente equivocado en algunas cosas como se puede apreciar en mi anterior respuesta que dejo más abajo como referencia de lo que es una mala respuesta, pero práctica :-)

---

**Anterior (mala) respuesta**

Cambia la `i` de ese bucle por una `j`, así:

```
function estadoAlumnos() {
    for(j = 0; j < alumnos.length; j++) {
        alumnos[j].promediando();            
    }
}
```

Por los motivos que sea, que desconozco realmente, le está pasando la variable `i` a la función `promediando` la cual incrementa el valor de `i` en otro bucle interno que tiene, y al regresar ya no continua porque ya es mayor que los elementos del objeto `alumnos`.

Tiene pinta de que eso ocurre por la forma de llamar a la función, como si de una propiedad del objeto se tratara, y al ocurrir eso dentro de un bucle que ya tenia definida la variable `i`, dicha variable amplia su ámbito hasta dentro de la función `promediando`, donde hay otro bucle que la reinicializa e incrementa su valor en el susodicho bucle interno de esa función, y al regresar al bucle de la función estadoAlumnos ya es demasiado grande para continuar.

De hecho se puede comprobar así:

```
function estadoAlumnos() {
  for (i = 0; i < alumnos.length; i++) {
    console.log(i)  
    alumnos[i].promediando();
    console.log(i)  
  }
}
```

donde la consola arroja estos datos:

```
0
6
```

Es decir, empieza en 0, y cuando regresa de la función `promediando` ya vale 6.

Comment: cuando declara el for sin hacer var i lo que hace es declarar implicitamente i como global, por eso el valor se mantiene despues del ciclo for porque queda como window.i en el dom

Comment: asi que la solucion tambien podria ser usar var para declarar la variable en cada ciclo for.

Comment: @StialManstike Muchas gracias :-) Acabo de actualizar mi respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias! efectivamente mi error fue no colocar dentro de for la variable declarada como let o var y eso elevaba el scope (según entiendo) de la variable a global

Comment: Efectivamente, si te has leido bien mi respuesta (puedes obviar la **respuesta mala**) es lo que intento explicar :-)  Si esta respuesta satisface tu pregunta deberias marcarla como aceptada para que la comunidad lo sepa y no quede pendiente para siempre. Para aprender a aceptar respuestas puedes mirar este [enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200). Saludos!

Comment: @HorusCamacho Tambien veo que aun no has realizado el [tour] para aprender como funciona este sitio, y donde explican tambien como se aceptan las respuestas válidas, y si lo haces podras ganar tu primera medalla!  Son dos minutejos y así aprenderás tambien como deben ser realizadas las preguntas y respuestas.